# BackRequested event handler event.Handled is ignored

Tags: c#, events, uwp

So, as per the docs I attach a handler when I navigate to a page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    /* Attach back listener to handle the back press */
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += NavigationPage_BackRequested;
            ...
}
```

And I detach it when leaving:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) {
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= NavigationPage_BackRequested;
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

And I mark the event as handled to prevent the system from handling it:

```
private void NavigationPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {

    e.Handled = true;

}
```

But the system still handles the back click and I get navigated away. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shown above is working fine (tested on my machine), but the big question is: do you try to cancel a system provided navigation event or a `Frame.GoBack()` event implemented by the software button of your application?

> SystemNavigationManager: Provides a way for an app to respond to system provided back-navigation events.

If you look at the [backwards navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation) documentation, only certain back buttons (hardware/software) are system provided events, e.g. the software button at the bottom in Tablet mode.

[image: Tablet mode]

However quite a few project templates (in Visual Studio or from MVVM libraries) also provide a software back button (quite often at the top left) and wire this event to the `Frame.GoBack()` method. This is NOT a system provided event and can't be cancelled this way. Reasoning: You (or the framework used) is calling the `GoBack()` explicitly, so why would it have to be cancelled in this scenario.